# Could job offer be by text message (SMS)?

Tags: job-offer, australia

I had this unlucky feeling about NXSMS text I received from Manpower Group Australia that I applied to. The text says that they are thankful of my application and that they have a job opening right now. If I am interested then I must text YES back.

I wonder if what should I expect next? Or do they send the text message to everyone? Could their text mean a real job offer?

Comment: I would imagine that they are collecting CVs / resumes. Also, replying shows them that you are on the market. Expect the sort of agency who goes on this sort of fishing expedition to also ask you for contact details of management in your area.

Comment: Dumb question: did you actually send an application to Manpower before receiving this text message? It's been 10 years since I dealt with them, but I'm a little surprised they would SMS rather than email

Comment: This is simply not **a job offer**. It has nothing to do with a job offer.  It's just an initial contact - an ad - to see if you are interested in talking to that agency.  No big deal.

Answer (score 10):

It's basically an opener to see if you're interested.  If you text back, they'll likely send you a more formal application form or call you to discuss further.

If you don't reply, they'll either chase again or send more SMS messages with other offers.

It's doubtful that this is a "real" job offer, more of an invitation to pursue an opportunity.